# A way to mark special row in a big table

Tags: database-design

Context: SQL Server 2008, ASP.NET MVC 2.0

I have table that lists forum topics.

```
|TopicId|Subject|Author|Views|LastUpdate|
```

I have a special forum topic that I use as a home-page "news" list. Such that message from that forum topic are listed as news.

Now I need somehow to indicate which forum topic is the news.

Here are some options:

**Add another column** called `|IsNewsForumTopic|`, but this feels an overkill, since other 10000 forum topics will always have set it to `false`.

**Store news-forum-topic in web.config** and do select based on that (don't like this approach also).

**Use a *database global variable*** in form of a storproc with NewsForumTopicId hardcoded.

**Create `NewsForumTopics` table** and manually add single record in there:

```
|NewsForumTopicId|
| 1174           |
```

I like this approach the most.

1. it doesn't take DB specific information out of the DB.
2. Doesn't affect big `ForumTopics` table.
3. I can add another column `|SpecialType|` enum-column later to maybe have a separate forum-topic for news, updates, and bug fixes.

Please criticize and/or suggest.

Comment: you should go with that approach as it's also the one i'd chose

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation where, no matter how you look at it, you need a hard-coded value in your system. Key questions here are:

- How likely is it to change over time?
- How bad is it if it gets mis-set somehow? (Bad configuration, or you get hacked)

I generally store such values in the database as per your `NewsForumTopics` table, but I would not do that for data that should *never* change. If that is the case, either hard-coding it in a stored procedure or burying it in a application config file seems wisest.

(And then there's the question "how to prevent some joker from ever deleting that one special entry", but that's a security issue to ask in your next SO question.)

Comment: It is unlikely to change after initial installation. If it is misconfigured wrong news be shown - no damage.

Answer (score 0):

Er, how about a special Author? `AuthorId = -1` or `AuthorName = 'news_bot'`. No schema changes involved.

If it is not too late in the project, you may also consider:

[image]

Comment: Won't this just shift the problem from "how do I mark forum-topic as special?" to "how do I mark author as special?"

Comment: @user93422, well every author is kind of special -- each has their own special name. Anyway, it seems that I do not fully understand the problem here.

Comment: when I say "special" in the context of the question it means "one corresponding to news page content". So if I do use magic Author to find news-forum-topic, then question is how do I decide which Author to use? Do I hard-code 'news_bot' in code? in web.config? or in stored proc.? or I could as well create a special forum-topic with subject "###news_bot"...except indexing subject makes less sense than indexing author name. So you might have a point here after all.